# Does the Press Keys functionality of Robot Framework allow for pressing few keys together followed by pressing few keys individually one after other?

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework

I wanted to replicate the following action CONTROL+END to reach the end of the page, followed by two Enter to reach a line where I want to paste a text for which I want to do CONTROL+v.

I am currently doing CONTROL+END+ENTER+ENTER+v. It is pasting the text but two lines above where I want to paste it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work, because you need to press keys in sequence. Your code presses all keys at the same time, so it pastes clipboard before cursor jumps to another field by pressing enter.

```
Press Keys  None  CTRL+END  ENTER  ENTER  CTRL+v
```

Comment: Yup it does the job. Thanks !